# Unhide Excel file that opens in C# with opening another one

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

I open an Excel file in C# with use of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace. The Excel file is hidden, but when I open any Excel file or application in Windows (without C#) the hidden file appears and I want to it remain hidden. What do you suggest to me to solve it?

Comment: How do you hide the file?

Comment: It is hidden by default. I use `excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add("excelfile.xlsx");` to open the Excel file, and it is hidden by default. I can unhide it with : `excelApp.Visible = true;`

Comment: Excel is a single-instance app, necessary because it is such a heavy process.  When you start a 2nd copy of excel.exe, it will go looking for another one that's already running.  It found one, asks it to load the file and quits.  First, just don't keep the instance that you created running.  Try setting the Application.MergeInstances property to false.

Comment: @HansPassant Is it me or this sounds like a pretty good answer ?

Comment: Sounds like one, no idea if it is an accurate one.

Comment: @HansPassant, Excel IS NOT single-instance app, you can run few instances of Excel.

Comment: Hmya, if that was really true then the OP would of course not have this problem.